# what is the use of ()=> in silverllight

Tags: c#, silverlight

Can you say what is the use of the `()=>` and `=>`? I saw this in a code. I did not get any reference for this.

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
{
    //some thing..
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This notation is that of a [**lambda expression**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) which takes no argument.  If the lambda expression made use of arguments they would be declared in the empty set of parenthesis as in say...

`this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((x, y) => { do some' with x and/or y },  12, somevar);`

In a nutshell, lambda expressions allows creating "nameless" functions, right where they are needed.
In the example of the question,  the *BeginInvoke()* method requires its first parameter to be a delegate (a "pointer to a method"), which is exactly what this lambda expression provides.

Answer (score 6):

`=>` is the [lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) in C# and is read as "goes to". A lambda expression is an anonymous function and can be used to create a delegate.

Your example takes no arguments as indicated by the empty parens preceding the lambda operator.  A lambda expression with one argument might look like this:

```
n => n.toString()
```

That expression would return the string representation of `n`, when invoked.  A lambda expression can have multiple arguments as well, contained in parentheses:

```
(n, f) => n.toString(f)
```

A common use would be in a `Func<T>`:

```
Func<int, string> getString = n => n.toString();
int num = 7;
string numString = getString(num);
```

This is, of course, a silly example, but hopefully helps to illustrate its use.

Answer (score 3):

It's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that has no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2008/11/27/back-to-basics-delegates-anonymous-methods-and-lambda-expressions/

> If you don’t have any parameters, like in our example, you use empty
>   paranthesis:
>
> () => {…}